# How to put text right to the Latex equation,

Tags: equations

I need to put the text right to the following equation, describing SVM kernels.
Does anybody know how to put the name of kernels just to the right (not above or below)    to the formula like:

```
 kernel 1
 kernel 2
 etc...

 \[
   K\left( {{X}_{i}},{{X}_{j}} \right)=
   \left\{ \begin{align}
     & {{X}_{i}}\bullet {{X}_{j}} \\ 
     & {{\left( \gamma {{X}_{i}}\bullet {{X}_{j}} \right)}^{d}} \\ 
     & \exp (-\gamma |{{X}_{i}}-{{X}_{j}}{{|}^{2}} \\ 
     & \tanh \left( \gamma {{X}_{i}}\bullet {{X}_{j}}+C \right) \\ 
  \end{align} \right\}
 \]
```

What tags to use, and in what order?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Your code contains an error. You should use `aligned` instead of `align`. Also, please always try to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Another note: you might also want to change `\bullet` to `\cdot`, unless the former has a meaning different from inner product.

Answer (score 3):

My best guess at what you want...

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align} % use align* if don't want equation numbered
  K\left( {{X}_{i}},{{X}_{j}} \right)=
  \left\{ \begin{aligned}
    & {{X}_{i}}\bullet {{X}_{j}} \\ 
    & {{\left( \gamma {{X}_{i}}\bullet {{X}_{j}} \right)}^{d}} \\ 
    & \exp (-\gamma |{{X}_{i}}-{{X}_{j}}{{|}^{2}} \\ 
    & \tanh \left( \gamma {{X}_{i}}\bullet {{X}_{j}}+C \right) \\ 
  \end{aligned} \right\} 
  && \text{[some kernel name]}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

u can simply use parallel tag to do that,first u need to import package parallel
then simply put equation code in left part and then put kernel names in the right part.
code for reference below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parallel}
\begin{document}
\begin{Parallel}[v]{0.48\textwidth}{0.48\textwidth}
\ParallelLText
{
  your equation code here
}
\ParallelRText
{
name of kernels here
}
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.